How to Configure Timefold to leave unassigned values in planning entity
I'm working on a scheduling problem where I need to assign technicians to service devices. However, in some cases, it is preferable to leave a device unassigned if no suitable technician (lack of demanded skills) is available (i.e., the device.pesel should be None). I've structured my domain model as follows:
@dataclass
class Technician:
    id: Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    pesel: str
    name: str
    rbh_per_week: int
    rbh_per_year: float
    rbh_week_plan: float
    selected_rbh: float
    free_rbh: float
    iums: Set[str]

    def has_ium(self, ium: str) -> bool:
        return ium in this.iums

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (f"Technician(id={self.id}, name={self.name}, pesel={self.pesel}, "
                f"rbh_per_week={self.rbh_per_week}, rbh_per_year={self.rbh_per_year}, "
                f"rbh_week_plan={self.rbh_week_plan}, selected_rbh={self.selected_rbh}, "
                f"free_rbh={self.free_rbh}, iums={self.iums})")

@planning_entity
@dataclass
class Device:
    index: Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    ind_rek: str
    ium: str
    nazwa: str
    typ: str
    nr_fab: str
    norma_rbh: float
    data_dostawy: str
    uzytkownik: str
    pesel: Annotated[Technician | None, PlanningVariable(value_range_provider_refs=['technicianRange'], nullable=True)] = field(default=None)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        technician_str = str(self.pesel) if self.pesel else "None"
        return (f"Device(index={self.index}, ind_rek={self.ind_rek}, ium={self.ium}, "
                f"nazwa={self.nazwa}, typ={self.typ}, nr_fab={self.nr_fab}, "
                f"norma_rbh={self.norma_rbh}, data_dostawy={self.data_dostawy}, "
                f"uzytkownik={self.uzytkownik}, assigned_technician={technician_str})")

@planning_solution
@dataclass
class DeviceSchedule:
    id: str
    technician_list: Annotated[List[Technician], ProblemFactCollectionProperty, ValueRangeProvider]
    device_list: Annotated[List[Device], PlanningEntityCollectionProperty]
    score: Annotated[HardSoftScore, PlanningScore] = field(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"DeviceSchedule("
            f"id={self.id},\n"
            f"technician_list={self.technician_list},\n"
            f"device_list={self.device_list},\n"
            f"score={self.score}"
            f")"
        )

My constraints are:
@constraint_provider
def define_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        # HARD constraint to avoid assigning a technician without the required skill
        technician_skill_conflict(constraint_factory),
    ]

def technician_skill_conflict(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (constraint_factory
            .for_each(Device)
            .filter(lambda device: device.pesel is not None and not device.pesel.has_ium(device.ium))
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .as_constraint("Technician skill conflict"))

The Problem:
Even though I have implemented the nullable=True option in the PlanningVariable, and I have defined a hard constraint that penalizes assigning a technician without the required skill, the solver still tends to assign a technician to every device, even when it would be better to leave the device unassigned.
My Question:
How should I structure my classes and constraints to ensure that the solver leaves the device.pesel as None when no suitable technician is available, without incurring hard penalties for leaving the device unassigned?
I will be appreciated for any insights or suggestions how to handle this situation.

This is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78740030/timefold-allowsunassigned-is-not-assigning-resources-even-with-0-constraints/78740746; the answer there will work for this.

Thank you very much! The PlanningVariable(allows_unassigned=True) option solved my problem. The documentation is primarily for Java, I code in Python so sometimes I have difficulty interpreting it.

You're right - we've only introduced the Python solver recently, so updating the docs to include the same level of examples for Python as we have for Java will take a while. Pull requests are welcome!
